# Karma & Jasmine - How to watch variables content and get notified?

Tags: angularjs, testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

Following scenario:

I have a controller with a method "LoginCtrl.login" which calls a service method "LoginService.login". My controller does the following:

- Set the login state variable to Pending
- Send a login Request to the server
- If success, set the login state to success

With jasmine, I want to test the given case above. So how can I watch a variable when it changed its value and get informed about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some code? Ideally the controller and the test you have attempting to test the controller. It will help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about watching variables/fields but you could make a setter for your state variable and spy on it with jasmine:

```
spyOn(controller, 'setState');

//do your stuff

expect(controller.setState).toHaveBeenCalled(); //toHaveBeenCalledWith(value)
```